# Creating a button for a HTTP GET request: problems with keeping the locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, internationalization, locale

I want to create a button with the help of the button_to method to navigate to a page where a new user friendship can be created.

```
<%= button_to t(:add_friend), new_user_friendship_url(current_user), :method => :get, :class => "btn-success" %>
```

(I do not want to use a link, i.e. not use link_to, because the styling of the buttons of the CSS framework I use look much better than the links).

Unfortunately, the button_to does not append the right locale as URL parameter. Is there anything I can do about it?

This is my application_controller.rb where I set the locale for every page request.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  protect_from_forgery

  def default_url_options(options={})
    logger.debug "default_url_options is passed options: #{options.inspect}\n"
    { :locale => I18n.locale }
  end
end
```

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, it should be easy to style buttons the same way links are styled.

secondly, i think that the problem is somewhere else in your code. if i put this in my app:

```
= button_to 'blaa', users_path(:locale => 'de')
```

i get a form like:

```
<form action="/users?locale=de" class="button_to" method="post"><div><input type="submit" value="blaa" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="k4PtVPS041DnTmTqkfh+xBIyFvVJCauenmg233BoLSw=" /></div></form>
```

and this button takes me to `http://localhost:5000/users?locale=de`

Comment: You are right, the CSS styling works for links as well. Don't know what produced the bad result when I was trying it out first. Thus I switched to links instead of buttons. Thanks!